# Where can I find 2160p video?

Tags: hdvideo, quad-hd

I've just ordered some monitors that can display 1080p video. When I orient them in a certain way, I'll be able to play back 2160p (**Quad HD**) video.

I've looked across the Internet (YouTube, download sites), but have been able to find very little 2160p video. Where can I find more?

Comment: I have a feeling you're going to have a hard time finding videos that large. Even Blu-Ray is only 1080p. :)

Comment: YouTube started offering much higher resolution quite a while ago: http://youtube-global.blogspot.de/2010/07/whats-bigger-than-1080p-4k-video-comes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

Barely anything whatsoever (Other than $10,000+ professional equipment) at the moment can record in higher than 1080p video - well, I have seen a few consumer products that "can" record at higher resolutions, but it is just digital magnification / the actual quality is beyond poor.

As for streaming, I can't even imagine what the required bandwidth would be. (but I guess it is usable - just wouldn't expect many sites to offer it for free).

Anything that can record natively at above 1080p is just far to expensive at the moment... And you will need the graphics horsepower to be able to play it back - there are no consumer players out there able to view it (computers are usually just an after thought) so without the entire eco-system, it just won't be popular for some time.

What I would recommend you do is get a good player that supports multi screens and upscale the content to play across all of them.

I know it isn't really what you want to hear, but I think until Quad HD becomes mainstream, it is going to be pretty much the best you can do.

Comment: This only applies to consumer video... professional video and cinematography has been shot at much higher resolutions than 1080p for some time now.

Comment: @emddudley Just for the fun of it, just been to the IFA Berlin and saw a 152" (!) Panasonic plasma screen with 4320p display displaying a downscaled clip shot at 8640p.

Comment: I have worked on several productions shot with the RED One, on location and in post production. Some of them student's projects. While it is true that it makes almost no sense to deliver 4K video right now, shooting and editing it is possible even at the amateur level.

Comment: @ischeriad - a Red one body alone (without lenses or extras) costs around $18,000 - you consider that amateur?

Comment: @Wil – Yes, since everybody from amateur to pro rents expensive equipment and does not buy it unless buying is cheaper in the long run. Rental companies do the buying.

Comment: @ischeriad - Fair enough, I know a few "amateurs" who rent £10k+ lenses for weekends or special events, but I personally still think that anyone who uses any of that sort of equipment to be a professional, even if only a basic professional.

Answer (score 3):

Some standardized resolutions above 1080P are 2K (2048x1080), 1440P (2560x1440), 4K (4096x2160), 2540P (4520x2540), and UHDTV/8k (7680x2540).

You can download a trailer for the short film *Crossing the Line* from http://www.red.com/shot_on_red/ (scroll down to the bottom). It was shot at 4k but I'm not sure if full sized clips are available. Some direct links are listed in the first post at http://www.redcamcentral.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17&sid=09c87e1c884eb681c6957452c1f85924

YouTube added some "4k" footage a while back... highly compressed. Not sure if it really counts. http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=5BF9E09ECEC8F88F

Answer (score 1):

For now [ATI Eyefinity](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/ati-eyefinity-technology/Pages/eyefinity.aspx) is the closest you can get to experiencing the Quad HD quality.

As for videos: Try to create a panorama video, according to Google it's possible... ;-)

Comment: Panoramic... *video*?  This is definitely worth looking into, especially considering I do panoramic *stills* as a hobby. Thanks.

Comment: There are two types, the one where you stitch the videos together (which is the one you will want) and the other one which allows you to rotate 360° (which is the one you don't want). I haven't looked further but http://content.photojojo.com/diy/videoramas-stitch-digital-video-panoramas/ is the idea, in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVhqA3Hi2YY at 1:06 there is another example... There is only one problem: If you want it to be simultaneous you are going to need 4 Full HD cams which is expensive, if you plan it right (still background, ...) you could create 4 separate videos with 1 camera.

Answer (score 0):

There is an episode of [MacBreak](http://www.pixelcorps.tv/macbreak) shot in 4K on a RED camera. You can [watch it on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UisJ0jeL4E) in its original resolution (note the choice "Original" above 1080p in the quality selector).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few examples of 2160p video located at http://media.xiph.org/video/derf/ (search on the page for the term "2160p".

These examples are raw movie files (only 500 frames at 5.8GB each) and are mostly used for performance testing. Typical application could be a 2x2 videowall running 1080p on each monitor, for example.